# Java String Concatenation with + operator

Tags: java, string

I got confused with the String concatenation.

```
String s1 = 20 + 30 + "abc" + (10 + 10);
String s2 = 20 + 30 + "abc" + 10 + 10;
System.out.println(s1);
System.out.println(s2);
```

The output is:

> 50abc20
>   50abc1010

I wonder why *20 + 30* are added together in both cases, but *10 + 10* require parenthese in order to be added (s1) instead of concatenated to the String (s2). Please explain how the String operator `+` works here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After a string literal, all the + will be treated as string concatenation operator why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34589340/after-a-string-literal-all-the-will-be-treated-as-string-concatenation-operat)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`+` can represent addition or concatenation.

- If both operands are numeric it is addition.
- If at least one operand is String it is concatenation.

Also addition and concatenation is left associative, so `a+b+c` is same as `(a+b)+c` (the `b` is associated with left `+`).

Taking the first case

```
20+30+"abc"+(10+10)  <--- here both operands are integers with the + operator, which is addition
-----       -------
  50 +"abc"+  20     <--- + operator on integer and string results in concatenation
  ---------
  "50abc"  +  20     <--- + operator on integer and string results in concatenation
    ------------
      "50abc20"
```

In the second case:

```
20+30+"abc"+10+10   <--- here both operands are integers with the + operator, which is addition
-----
  50 +"abc"+10+10   <--- + operator on integer and string results in concatenation
  ---------
   "50abc"  +10+10  <--- + operator on integer and string results in concatenation
    ----------
    "50abc10"  +10  <--- + operator on integer and string results in concatenation
     ------------
      "50abc1010"
```

Answer (score 2):

Also, to add to this topic, as the wrong part of the answer of Jonathan Schober tipped me off on a thing to keep in mind:

**`a+=something` is not equal to `a=a+<something>`** : the `+=` evaluates the right side first, and only then adds it to the left side. So it has to be rewritten, it is equivalent to:

```
a=a+(something); //notice the parentheses!
```

Showing the difference

```
public class StringTest {
  public static void main(String... args){
    String a = "";
    a+=10+10+10;

    String b = ""+10+10+10;

    System.out.println("First string, with += : " + a);
    System.out.println("Second string, with simple =\"\" " + b);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the concept of associativity, you could ensure that two integers are never added together by using parentheses to always pair a string with an integer so the desired concatenation operation will take place rather than an addition.

```
String s4 = ((20 + (30 + "abc")) + 10)+10;
```

would produce:

```
2030abc1010
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to start with an empty string.

So, this might work:

```
String s2 = ""+20+30+"abc"+10+10;
```

Or this:

```
String s2 ="";
s2 = 20+30+"abc"+10+10;
System.out.println(s2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to know some rules:
1, Java operator priority,most of the left-to-right
2, Brackets priority than **+** sign priority.
3, The result is sum,if both sides of  **+** sign are integer,  else is concatenation.