# Sum an array value with a variable in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I want to sum an array value with an int, but I don't know how. My array contains a value that I don't know, because I read it from a file. I want to sum the number inside the array with a number inside a variable, this is my code:

```
int number = 2;
array[0] += number;
System.out.println(array[0]);
```

But it doesn't work, because if, for example, the value of array[0] is 1, the system will print 12 and not 1+2=3

UPDATE: I made a big mistake, the value inside the array was a String and I didn't know that, so obviously I can't sum a string with an Integer. 
But if I know that the string contains only numbers, then I have to parse the content of it by using Integer.parseInt(string) and then I can sum his value.

Comment: Is array is a string array?

Comment: I bet your array is defined as `String[] array...`

Comment: _"read it from a file"_ so it's probably a string.  Unless you manually convert it with stuff like `scanner.nextInt()` or something.

Comment: Hey, I just thought of something, is it an array of `String`s?

Comment: @ iamnotmaynard did you read the comments above yours?

Comment: Is it an `int[]` comprising exclusively of the number `10`? (yeah, let's think of *all* the possibilities ;)

Comment: @ShireResident Why? What do they say?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After a string literal, all the + will be treated as string concatenation operator why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34589340/after-a-string-literal-all-the-will-be-treated-as-string-concatenation-operat)

Comment: Also see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your array is a `String[]`, summing the value to an `int` as you do will concatenate (`"12"`) instead of performing an arithmetic sum (`3`).

One idiom to resolve that would be:

```
array[0] = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(array[0]) + number);
```

Beware, you'll need to catch `NumberFormatException` in case `array[x]` cannot be inferred as a number.

Also beware of `null` elements in your `String[]`.

Answer (score 1):

Your array have string objects that's why. First you have to convert string object into integer.

```
array[0] = (Integer.parseInt(array[0]) + 2) + "";
```

Comment: That won't compile - you're assigning an `int` value to a `String`.

Comment: @mena right. My bad. I thought it's array of int. But that's just a rought idea for implementation. Just add + "" after that. It should work fine

Comment: I'd recommend you edit your answer - it's an easy fix.