# Why does '+' operator behave abnormally in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, operators, concatenation, string-concatenation, arithmetic-expressions

I'm learning JavaScript.

I tried putting double quotes around different digits in an JavaScript expression and I got surprised with the third result from below code statements.

Consider below code statements and their output present in a comment ahead of each code line.

```
var x = "5" + 2 + 3;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x; //Output is : **523**

var x = 5 + "2" + 3;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x; //Output is : **523**

var x = 5 + 2 + "3";
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x; //Output is : **73**
```

Can someone please explain why and how the '+' operator behaves abnormally in JavaScript?

Why the output of last statement is not **523** since one of the digits is a string?

Please explain me in a simple and lucid language.

Thanks.

Comment: Javascript works in left to right way while doing operations
so when it gets 2 numbers it sum ups and the binds with the string

Comment: Does this previous discussion help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15340207/java-string-concatenation-with-operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript executes the expressions left-to-right. So in the last example it will do this:

```
5 + 2 => 7
7 + "3" => "73"
```

Hope that helps

Comment: `5 + "2"` and `"5" + 2` both evaluate to `"52".  It's not just because of the evaluation order, it's because of the coercion rules.

Comment: That is correct of course, but we have 3 summands here, that is why we do not see "523".

Answer (score 2):

'+' is not behaving abnormally.

You are not getting the concept right. 
+ operator act as as concatenation operator when used with strings and act as an addition operator when used with digits.

Answer (score 2):

The `+` operator does two things in javascript.  For strings it concatenates (joins them).  For numbers, it adds them.  If you use `+` on a combination of a number and a string, javascript *coerces* them into something it can act on.

In your case, a `string` `+` a `number` coerces into two strings.  Then it concatenates.

```
var x = "5" + 2 + 3;
// coerced by runtime into var x = "5" + "2" + "3";
// x = "523";
```

In your later case, you have two numbers before the string.  In this case, the evaluation order kicks in.  The runtime first evaluates the arithmetic *before* coercing it to a string to concatenate

```
var x = 5 + 2 + "3";
//arithmetic performed var x = 7 + "3";
//coerced to var x = "7" + "3";
//x = "73";
```

Answer (score 0):

parse the statements from left to right

```
var x = "5" + 2 + 3;
=> ("5" + 2) + 3;   //the + works as string concatenation since one operand is a string
=>  "52" + 3 
=>  "523" 

    var x = 5 + "2" + 3;
    //same for this one as above

var x = 5 + 2 + "3";
    => (5 + 2) + "3";   //the + works as an add operator because both oerands are numbers
    =>  7 + "3"         //the + works as string concatenation since one operand is a string 
    =>  "73"
```

Answer (score 0):

in `var x= 5 + "2" + 3`, first operation is appending beacause one of the operand is String.

in  `var x = 5 + 2 + "3"`, first two operands are integers, so it will be added and then append with String value 3, that is why you are getting 73.

After all the answer is simple, JS expressions are executing here from left side since all operators here are same( +, equal priority)